# Back button on Chrome makes Javascript to be reinterpreted but not in Firefox/IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, back-button

I am building a page where a user can edit an object, through React components <sup><sub>(The question does not concern React directly, no need of expertise in this framework)</sub></sup>. For performance and simplicity, the initial object is stored in JSON in the HTML sent to the user and every React components are initialized with this object.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>var OBJ = {'foo': 'bar', 'foo2': 'baz'};</script>

    <body>...

        <script src="my_react_components.jsx"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Each component is loaded in a `$(document).ready()` and everything is fine at the first access of the page. However, while testing on Chrome, I noticed a strange behaviour. With these steps:

- Load the page
- Edit a property of the object, through a React component (in my app: click on it, a form opened, then an AJAX request is sent on validation. Internally, OBJ is now equal to `{'foo': 'new_bar', 'foo2': 'baz'}` for example)
- The page is modified to take into account the new property value
- Click on any link, that redirect to another page
- Hit back button

The user gets back to the first page but with the initial properties, which can be confusing ("Hum, I did update this value before"). This happens only on Chrome. Firefox and IE 10 seems to working fine, displaying the last HTML view the user had before leaving the page.

I believe the BFCache [implemented in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_BFCache) might differ from the one in Chrome (which keeps the HTML but replays the Javascript). Indeed, if I try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Click</a>
    <script>console.log('test');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`test` is displayed in the console in Chrome if we come from the back button but not in Firefox...

How can I workaround this? I don't know if it is relevant, but [Chromium have an open issue for 2 years more of less related](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=344507&can=5&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).